# MongoDB Aggregation Error: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field

Tags: mongodb, nosql, dataset, aggregation, tweets

I am trying to get the `screen_name` and `FriendsToFollowerRatio` from a dataset of tweets that matches the Pacific Time Zone, when I try to run the query below I get the error:

> MongoServerError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

```js
db.tweets.aggregate([
  {$match:{time_zone:"Pacific Time (US & Canada)", verified:false}},
  {$project:{screen_name:true},
     FriendstoFollowersRatio:{$divide:["$friends_count", "$followers_count"]}
  }
])
```

Not really sure why it is happening as I've seen another example with pretty much the same format and it worked so I must be getting it wrong somewhere, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is referring to the fact that the second stage in your pipeline (intended to be a `$project`) actually has two documents inside of it. This is because your nesting for `FriendstoFollowersRatio` is wrong.  Formatted, your current pipeline is:

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
         "verified":false
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "screen_name":true
      },
      "FriendstoFollowersRatio":{
         "$divide":[
            "$friends_count",
            "$followers_count"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

It should instead have that field nested inside of the `$project`:

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
         "verified":false
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "screen_name":true,
         "FriendstoFollowersRatio":{
           "$divide":[
              "$friends_count",
              "$followers_count"
           ]
        }
      }
   }
]
```

[Playground link here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MvYkCycGtNK)